# Jtable align text both on left and right in the same line

Tags: java, swing, jtable

**Trying to achieve this on Jtable.**

I was trying to align two words like one on left side and another on right side but in the same line.

```
String html="<html><div style='float:left;width:50%;'>left</div><div style='float:right;width:50%;'>right</div></html>";
Object rowData[][] = { { html, "Column2-data"}};
```

unfortunately it didn't work. I tried with **p** tag and **font** tag as well.

**Please help me on how can I achieve this using HTML tags.**

Comment: Why the requirement on the HTML tags ?

Comment: You can do anything you want in your [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) of `TableCellRenderer`.

Comment: @Robin Wanted to customize the text within a cell with different color,font,align etc...  without html tags if it can be achieved please suggest me.

Comment: As you already noticed not all HTML tags/options are supported in Swing. You can consider using a `JTextPane` as renderer

Comment: Do you want center justification or full justification?  Because with full justification, you're going to have to add the extra inter-text spaces yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own table cell renderer to center the text in your JTable

```
public class CenterCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            JLabel renderedLabel = (JLabel) super
                    .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                            hasFocus, row, column);
            renderedLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            return renderedLabel;
        }
    }
```

To use this table cell renderer for the entire table:

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = new CenterCellRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
```

To define a column specific renderer, you need to define a `JTable` subclass that overrides the `getCellRenderer` method

```
table = new JTable(...) {
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        if (column == 2) {
            return renderer;
        }
        // else...
        return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
    }
};
```

Now that I've thought about your question a bit more, I'd put the text in two columns.  If necessary, you can right align the text in the second column using a right justify cell renderer similar to the one I created for centering text.

Comment: I would say that either you use a JPanel with BorderLayout embedding two JLabel's (one on the WEST, the other on the EAST), or split the column model in two columns and use appropriate alignement for the renderer. Congrats for your 10k